# Setting cue points in XML for use in Flash Video

Tags: flash, actionscript, cue-points

We need to set up a system for a client which needs to be super simple for them to be able to do in future and I was wondering if it is possible to set cue points in an XML file which are then pulled into the swf along with the FLV. The cue points will be managed by the client so that they can change slides and images during the process of the video playing.

I know that there are hardcoded cue points which can be set up during FLV creation and one can set cue points using AS. I would like to know if it is possible to set those AS cue points using XML?

Also, do we have to use a streaming server (CDM) to get this right or will we be able to stream the video directly from the client's site?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can get cue points from xml file, you just need to check netstream.time on enterframe to response cue points. You can make a eventdispacher class for this to let you know cue points that works like netstream onCuePoint